# lost DVB Sky driver after update kernel

Tags: drivers, dvb

Spending a lot of time in getting Kodi right, I finally installed my TV remote control an (keymapping) and DVB card. Got it all working. But after the kernel installation, its update  from 3.16.0-41 to 3.16.0-43 lead me to loose my drivers and everything. It is driving me insane. `dmesg | grep -i dvb` gives no results.

I tried to rebuild the drivers again by executing the build script and running `make` and `sudo make install`. It appears to me that the make is relating the build to the old kernel 41...

How can I get it right and prevent it from ruining my system after future kernel updates?

who can give a clue? The build_x64.sh script copies files linux drivers.

kind regards,

```
#!/bin/bash    
cp ./v4l/sit2_op.o.x64 ./v4l/sit2_op.o
cp ./v4l/sit2_mod.dvb ./linux/drivers/media/dvb-frontends/sit2_mod.c
```

Comment: Try to run make clean before running make && sudo make install, it ma be configured to install the drivers into the old kernel. Just a long shot though.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of applications and drivers have a `./configure` stage that sets up the project and works out what it'll be linking against. Some have it built into their `make` script. The annoying thing (TBS does this with their V4L drivers) is it won't run again until you run a `make clean`. This nukes all the configuration and should reset the driver back to an initial state.

I've gone one further for my TBS card. I've scripted something that downloads the latest driver from TBS, unpacks the fresh version and then compiles from that. Here's a starter for you:

```
LATEST=$(wget -qO- http://www.tbsdtv.com/download/ | grep -oPm1 'download.+tbs-linux-drivers[^"]+')
echo "Getting $LATEST"
wget -q "http://www.tbsdtv.com/$LATEST"
7z -y x tbs-linux-drivers*
```

It also has a rename step where it renames a bunch of modules for 64bit use. You could just call the script from your script... or you could replace it with a `rename`. Here's what I do:

```
rename 's/\.x86_64$//' v4l/*
```

Though it looks like you'll need to replace `x86_64` with `x64`.

It's rubbish like this that makes me wish I'd bought hardware with mainline drivers.

Comment: thanks for answers and the comments. "sudo make clean" did not work out: the v4l drivers are still bound to the old version of the kernel.

A simple solution (which I forgot) is to use the old kernel at startup...

But I removed the builddirectory of the dvbsky files. I extracted the original files. I ran the buildscript, make, make install and it worked out fine. The drivers were re-installed. Happily the udev rules and keymaps still work.

After my holiday I will try the script (with modifications for my situation).